# r histogram assigns wrong number of observations to each bin

Tags: r, count, histogram, frequency

Below is the data I am working with. I do a simple hist(data) and the frequency of -.3 through .4 are correct. However, for some reason R seems to combine the frequency of -.5 and -.4, the two left most bins. There are 3 counts of -.5 and 5 counts of -.4, but R plots 8 counts of both -.5 and -.4.

Any idea why this may be going on? How to fix it?

```
  [1] -0.1  0.0  0.1  0.1  0.3  0.0  0.0  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.2  0.1 -0.1  0.2  0.0
 [16] -0.4  0.2  0.0 -0.1  0.0  0.1  0.1 -0.1  0.0  0.0  0.1  0.0 -0.1  0.0  0.3
 [31] -0.2  0.4 -0.1  0.0 -0.2  0.0  0.1  0.1  0.0  0.1  0.2 -0.1  0.1  0.1 -0.1
 [46]  0.2  0.1 -0.1  0.1  0.0 -0.1  0.4 -0.1 -0.1  0.0  0.0 -0.1  0.1  0.1  0.0
 [61]  0.1 -0.1  0.2 -0.1  0.1 -0.1  0.0  0.1  0.0  0.1  0.0  0.1  0.0 -0.1  0.1
 [76]  0.2 -0.2  0.0  0.0 -0.1  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.0 -0.3  0.0 -0.1 -0.1  0.1 -0.2
 [91] -0.1 -0.3 -0.1 -0.3 -0.2 -0.2  0.0  0.0  0.0 -0.2  0.1  0.0  0.0  0.1  0.0
[106]  0.0 -0.2 -0.1  0.2 -0.1  0.0 -0.1 -0.1 -0.2  0.1  0.1  0.0  0.1  0.2  0.1
[121]  0.0  0.1 -0.2  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.1  0.1  0.0 -0.1  0.1  0.0  0.1 -0.1  0.2
[136]  0.0  0.1  0.1  0.0  0.1 -0.1  0.0  0.0  0.1  0.2 -0.1  0.1  0.0  0.1  0.0
[151] -0.1  0.0  0.2  0.1 -0.1  0.1 -0.2  0.1  0.1 -0.1  0.1 -0.2 -0.1  0.1 -0.1
[166]  0.0  0.0 -0.3  0.0  0.1 -0.2  0.1 -0.4 -0.2 -0.2 -0.3  0.0 -0.4 -0.3 -0.5
[181] -0.5 -0.5 -0.4 -0.3 -0.4 -0.1  0.0 -0.1 -0.2 -0.2  0.1  0.0  0.2 -0.1 -0.1
[196]  0.0  0.3  0.2 -0.1  0.0  0.0  0.0 -0.3  0.4  0.3  0.1  0.0 -0.1  0.1 -0.1
[211]  0.1  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.2  0.1  0.3 -0.1  0.1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.1  0.3
[226]  0.0  0.0 -0.1  0.0  0.2  0.2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.1  0.0  0.0  0.2  0.3
[241]  0.1 -0.1  0.0  0.4  0.0  0.2 -0.1  0.1
```

Here is the output of the histogram. You can see 8 counts of -.5 and -.4, which isn't in the data

```
$breaks
 [1] -0.5 -0.4 -0.3 -0.2 -0.1  0.0  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4

$counts
 [1]  8  8 17 46 75 60 23  7  4
```

Comment: This is the algorithm but you can force the counts to be the same as the table of counts; have a look at the counts with `right=FALSE` or specify the number of breaks `hist(x, right=FALSE, breaks=seq(-0.5, 0.5, 0.1))$counts`. Although this is perhaps more of a barplot.

Answer (score 0):

The comments above explain what's happening - the breaks are the left and right limits of the intervals, not the centers.

How to fix it? If you are dealing just with numbers discretized to [natural numbers] * 0.1 you can set your breaks at 0.05, 0.15, ... by

```
data <- c(-0.5, -0.5, 0.4) 
breaks <- ((min(data)*10):(max(data)*10+1))/10-0.05
result <- hist(data, breaks)
```

But is a histogram really that what you need for this? It seems that you just want to calculate the number of occurrences which is much easier by

```
data <- c(-0.5, -0.5, 0.4) 
aggregate(data, list(data), "length")
```

returning

```
  Group.1 x
1    -0.4 2
2     0.6 1
```

And for plotting, have a look at `barplot`